# Parse send push notification before app is opened

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

Is it possible to send a push notification to a device on which the application hasn't been opened yet? (but is installed).

Comment: I can't think of a way, as the device needs to 'subscribe to a channel' before it can receive push notifications. So my understanding would be that the earliest you would be able to make a device subscribe to push notifications would be the first time the application was started.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Because you have to ask for registering the device to get the token.

```
UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Font: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS